# Request::$controller in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Why I cannot request a used controller's name from the View?

For example, someview.php contains:

`<?php
     echo Request::$controller;
?>`

Kohana shows the error: “ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Access to undeclared static property: Request::$controller”

Why? What's wrong?

It is needed for me for doing this:

`<?php if (Request::$controller != 'index') { ?>
    <a href="/">Example.com</a>
<?php } else { ?>
     Example.com
<?php } ?>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this instead, on the controller :

```
View::bind_global('controller', $this->request->param('controller'));
```

Then you can access `$controller` on any view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yoda! Is this the only one right solution in my case?

Comment: You're not supposed to call objects directly on the views, so yes. Still, there are many ways of doing it, but you'll end up always setting a variable to each view .. This way it's global, not extra work needed.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try to use `bind_global` as you said, Kohana says: “ErrorException [ Strict ]: Only variables should be passed by reference”. Using `set_global` instead of `bind_global` works but the `$controller` variable became always empty.

Comment: @Azat `bind` in Kohana refers to setting by reference - the example above binds when it should be set. And getting the controller name should be done with `Request::$controller`.

Comment: @alex, it works both ways, but yes Request::$controller should be better. Binds always worked for me.

Comment: @yoda: `$this->request->controller` instead of `$this->request->param('controller')` works.

Comment: @alex, `Request::$controller` doesn't work for me in my template controller. The class names declader like this: `class Controller_DefaultTemplate extends Controller_Template` and it is for the whole site. I don't know why it works only with `$this->request->controller` but don't works with `Request::$controller`, even we use binding.

Comment: Does Controller_DefaultTemplate even work? Can you pastebin your controller?

Comment: Yes, it works. Here it is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17136439/net/stackoverflow/2011_02_03__05_31__UTC_p_05_00.rtf

Comment: @yoda: It works like I said earlier, but does not use `Request::$controller`

Answer (score 3):

Request should be accessed by it's static methods, there's no need to define additional static properties || global view vars to get it.

`Request::instance()` will return the the main request instance ('mother instance').
`Request::current()` will return the instance of the currently active request, the same thing you can access with `$this->request` in Controller.

```
<? if (Request::current()->controller !== 'index') : ?> 

    <a href="<?= URL::site() ?>">Example.com</a> 

<? else : ?> 

    Example.com 

<?  endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great, Kemo. This is what I needed. Hope this is the best solution in my case.

Comment: It's the only right solution (passing controller to view would be an overkill, so yeah) :)

Comment: not at all, if you have multiple requests. Also, it's better to have a variable rather than calling a method each time you need that info.

Comment: Kemo, thank you for your great solution, but I've decided to follow the suggestion that says the View should have as simple code as it possible (in our case it is a simple variable).

Comment: ofcourse, I practice that theory as well but in this case there is no need to set a variable, at least in my opinion. The overhead is minimal (request's getter returns a reference), although it does look kind of ugly and not-in-place (calling a static method in view at all).

Answer (score 1):

I would do as yoda suggested, however I would probably put that logic in the controller as well.

I assume you want a link back to home?

```
$link = (Request::$controller != 'index') ? '<a href="/">Example.com</a>' : 'Home';
$this->template->set_global('homeLink', $link);
```

Don't forget too you can build links from your routes by using `Route::get()` or one of its friends.

Comment: Yeah, I want the link to the root page of the site not to be shown when the user stays on the root page of the site already. The link to the root page should be shown only if a user on another pages of the site.

Comment: It is still says “Access to undeclared static property: Request::$controller” :( Maybe, I do something wrong in other place?

Comment: @Azat Are you in a controller context? Try `$this->request->controller`.

Comment: @alex: I was in a template controller context. Now all works. I use `bind_global` and `$this->request->controller`. Is this the best way to solute my task? Is requesting such info like controller's name directly from the View (like I done before) a bad decision?

Comment: @Azat A view should not talk to anything IMO - it should be assigned all data it needs to get the job done - and logic like this should be performed in the controller, and the resulting data itself should be passed to the view.

Comment: @alex, do you want say the View should not have deal with such difficult things (and all these things should be done in controller), right?

Comment: @Azat Yes - the view's job is to display the data - and only perform trivial logic, e.g. `<?php if ($list): ?> <ul><?php echo $list; ?></ul> <?php endif; ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

In Kohana 3.1

```
<? if (Request::current()->controller !== 'index') : ?>
```

give the "ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Request::$controller". then i simply using Request::current()->controller() in view acceptable/ best practice/ optimal performance?

```
<? if (Request::current()->controller() !== 'index') : ?> 

    <a href="<?= URL::site() ?>">Example.com</a> 

<? else : ?> 

    Example.com 

<?  endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Kohana 3.2: In the controller, paste this (I find it really really stupid that you can't use bind_global)

```
View::set_global('controller', $this->request->current()->controller());
```

Then in the view, you can use:

```
echo ( $controller );
```